# Would anyone like to create a community ad?

Tags: discussion

I think cooking folks would probably be happy to serve a community ad for y'all. It'd be awesome if someone would make one!

There are pre-made community ads from area51, but they're not exactly exciting:

[area51 ad http://area51.stackexchange.com/ads/proposal/48905.png](http://area51.stackexchange.com/ads/proposal/48905.png)

Simple images with text often work out pretty well; see for example [the current community ads on cooking](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2152/1672).

The image requirements:

> - The image that you create must be **300 x 250 pixels**, or double that if high DPI.
> - Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
> - Must be GIF or PNG
> - No animated GIFs
> - Absolute limit on file size of **150 KB**
> - **If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.**

Comment: this is a great idea ill have ago see if i can make anything

Comment: Great idea!  Let's think about other graduated sites where targeted ads might make sense, too.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Beer, Wine & Spirit]

Well here is my attempt its not 100% needs to have the image a bit sharper and its a bit bland but I though I would get the ball rolling